# Generate a unique code and hide i

Tags: java, web-services, spring

I'm writing a web service server side with spring. My first request is getUniqueID. I create a unique id for this request and return to client it. Then other client requests ınput must be this id. How can I hide this id on server side?

Comment: Add it to the session object for this client?

Answer (score 0):

If your `hide` means persist, it's best to save it to some relational database. If you don't need full-blown RDBMS, I can recommend SQLite. More: http://www.sqlite.org/
You will also need a way to map your user to that id. This is only possible if your web service is stateful. You can use HTTP session.

You can use Spring JDBC support to make persisting and querying your ids very simple.
More here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what you mean by `hide this id on server side`?  Also, what will the id be used for in future service requests?

You can put the id in the session so the client doesn't need to know about it. This simplifies subsequent service calls by the client as it wouldn't need to pass the id around each time.

If you want to use the session, Spring has some nice helper methods in `WebUtils` that may be helpful.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/WebUtils.html